# Is $f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2}+x) & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

How to check if this function continuous at $x = 0$?

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2}+x) & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}$$

What I have tried?
I tried to calculate the right hand limit and the left side limit and I got:

$\lim_{x \to 0^\mathtt{\text{+}}} x^{2} \sin{\left(x + \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right)}=0$

$\lim_{x \to 0^\mathtt{\text{-}}} x^{2} \sin{\left(x + \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right)}=0$

And $f(0) = 0$

By the definition this function is continues at $x=0$ but in the answers it is written that there is a point of discontinuity at $x=0$

Comment: What is the definition of continuity you are working with? What have you tried to answer the question?

Comment: Are you sure you have the question right? That is a function whose _derivative_ at $0$ is not continuous (and indeed unbounded in every neighbourhood of $0$), even though it is differentiable everywhere. So perhaps you were asked whether the derivative is continuous?

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $0$ and, in point of fact, it's differentiable.

Comment: The source of the question is formulated as follows: Is a function integrable at $[-10,10]$?And then it says $-100\leq f(x) \leq$ and then and then write that the function is continuous except for a finite number of points because $f$ is not continues at $0$ and is therefore integrable. But now I assume there is mistake in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $-1 \leq $ sin $(x+1 /x^2) \leq 1$. Now multiply both sides by $x^2$ and by sandwich rule you could get that $x^2$sin$(x+1 /x^2)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$ and which is $f(0)$. So the given function is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know that answering questions which show almost zero effort from the asker is against the site policy, as outlined in the recent [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: @insipidintegrator I fixed the question, thank you,